# UI Activity View Errors

Tags: ios

I'm quite the beginner to iOS Programming, and I googled how to get the UI Activity View implemented, but I'm getting errors that I do not quite understand. Anyone that can help me figure out what the errors mean in more specific detail and how to fix them, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#pragma mark - SHARING OPTIONS (using a DocumentInteractionController) =============
/* =================
 NOTE: The following methods work only on real device, not iOS Simulator, and you should have apps like Instagram, iPhoto, etc. already installed into your device!
 ================= */
-(void)shareImageToAllAppsAvailable {

    NSLog(@"This code works only on device. Please test it on iPhone!");

    // makes an NSURL file to the processed Image that needs to be saved
    NSURL *fileURL;
    docIntController.delegate = self;

    //Saves the Image to default device directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My Selfie.jpg"];
    UIImage *image = combinedImage;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

    //Load the Image Path
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My Selfie.jpg"];
    // this blank line here creates error 'use of undeclared identifier 'showActivityViewController''

    // Create the URL path to the Image to be saved
    fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:getImagePath];

    // Open the Document Interaction controller for Sharing options

    -(void)showActivityViewController
    {
        //-- set up the data objects
        NSString *textObject = _aTextView.text;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My Selfie.jpg"];
        NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textObject, url, image, nil];

        //-- initialising the activity view controller
        UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                         initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                         applicationActivities:nil];

        //-- define the activity view completion handler
        avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
            NSLog(@"Activity Type selected: %@", activityType);
            if (completed) {
                NSLog(@"Selected activity was performed.");
            } else {
                if (activityType == NULL) {
                    NSLog(@"User dismissed the view controller without making a selection.");
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Activity was not performed.");
                }
            }
        };

}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what errors you're getting if you don't tell us?

Comment: @esqew Just updated.

Comment: Do a clean. Still, I didn't see where is called `showActivityViewController`. I guess there was a line before calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing `}` before your `-(void)showActivityViewController` declaration.

It looks like you're trying to call that method by defining it within another method, which is not valid Objective-C. Use the `self` construct to reference methods defined in the same class.

```
#pragma mark - SHARING OPTIONS (using a DocumentInteractionController) =============
/* =================
 NOTE: The following methods work only on real device, not iOS Simulator, and you should have apps like Instagram, iPhoto, etc. already installed into your device!
 ================= */
-(void)shareImageToAllAppsAvailable {

    NSLog(@"This code works only on device. Please test it on iPhone!");

    // makes an NSURL file to the processed Image that needs to be saved
    NSURL *fileURL;
    docIntController.delegate = self;

    //Saves the Image to default device directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My Selfie.jpg"];
    UIImage *image = combinedImage;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

    //Load the Image Path
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"My Selfie.jpg"];
    // this blank line here creates error 'use of undeclared identifier 'showActivityViewController''

    // Create the URL path to the Image to be saved
    fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:getImagePath];

    // Open the Document Interaction controller for Sharing options
    [self showActivityViewController]; //added
} //added

-(void)showActivityViewController
{
    //-- set up the data objects
    NSString *textObject = _aTextView.text;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"My Selfie.jpg"];
    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textObject, url, image, nil];

    //-- initialising the activity view controller
    UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                     initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                     applicationActivities:nil];

    //-- define the activity view completion handler
    avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed){
        NSLog(@"Activity Type selected: %@", activityType);
        if (completed) {
            NSLog(@"Selected activity was performed.");
        } else {
            if (activityType == NULL) {
               NSLog(@"User dismissed the view controller without making a selection.");
            } else {
               NSLog(@"Activity was not performed.");
            }
        }
    };
}
```